# Delphi console application: how to add OnHelp to message dialogs?

Tags: delphi, console

I have a Delphi console application that updates components on a server.  It runs semi-interactively, there's the occasional prompt "are you sure?" etc, via this code:

```
MessageDlg('Are you sure?', mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo, mbHelp], SOME_HELP_CONTEXT)...
```

As you can see, I'd like to supply help links to it, in this case going to our website with `SOME_HELP_CONTEXT` appended to our help page: `?contextid=SOME_HELP_CONTEXT`

I am doing this from our GUI programs and I assign `Application.OnHelp := myHelper;` where `myHelper` is a method of an object which simply calls `ShellExecute` to open the web link.

But there's no Application variable in a console app.

Is there a fairly simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using the `Dialogs` unit, you already have the `Application` variable. Because, `Dialogs` uses `Controls`, which initializes the `Application` variable that is in the `Forms` unit. All you have to do is to additionally use the `Forms` unit in your code.

```pascal
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Forms, Winapi.Windows;

type
  THelper = class
  protected
    function OnHelp(Command: Word; Data: THelpEventData; var CallHelp: Boolean): Boolean; virtual;
  end;

{ THelper }

function THelper.OnHelp(Command: Word; Data: THelpEventData;
  var CallHelp: Boolean): Boolean;
begin
  MessageBox(GetActiveWindow, PChar(Format('help request about "%d"', [Data])), '', 0);
  CallHelp := False;
end;

var
  Helper: THelper;
begin
  try
    Helper := THelper.Create;
    Application.OnHelp := Helper.OnHelp;
    MessageDlg('Are you sure?', mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo, mbHelp], 5);
    Helper.Free;
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: FYI, you can use `class` methods as event handlers, so you can declare `THelper.OnHelp` as a `class` method, and then get rid of the `Helper` object instance: `Application.OnHelp := THelper.OnHelp;`

Comment: Indeed, just make sure it isn't a *static* class method.